# Differentiating under the Integral in the proof of the Cramér-Rao bound

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, statistics

I've looked at various proofs of the Cramér-Rao bound, but they all seem to lack rigour when dealing with why one is allowed to differentiate under the integral.

Consider a (continuous or discrete) random variable $X$ with density $f_\theta$ on a statical space $(\Omega,F,(P_\theta)_{\theta\in\Theta})$ where $\Theta$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $h : \Theta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $d(X)$ be an unbiased estimator for $h$. Then it holds by assumption that $E_\theta(d(X)) = h(\theta)$. Now the standard proof of the Cramér-Rao bound goes something like this:

As $d(X)$ is unbiased, we have
$h(\theta) = \int d(x) f_\theta(x) dx$. Therefore $h'(\theta) = \partial_\theta \int d(x)f_\theta(x) dx$ (where $\partial_\theta$ denotes the partial derivative in the $\theta$ direction). Differentiating under the integral gives $h'(\theta) = \int d(x) \partial_\theta f_\theta(x) dx$ and if $f(x) \neq 0 $ then we get something like $h'(\theta) = E_\theta(d(X)\partial_\theta ln(f_\theta X))$. The rest of the inequality follows from Cauchy-Schwartz.

Now my question regards why we are allowed to differentiate under the integral. So far all we've assumed is that $d$ is in $L^2$; if I'm not mistaken to use Leibnitzs' rule we need certain continuity assumptions on $d$ for the continous case (or uniform convergence of partial sums of $ \sum_{x} d(x) \partial_\theta f_\theta(x)$ for the discrete case), and I don't see how these follow from the fact that $d$ is in $L^2$. I feel like I'm probably missing something obvious, and would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have a look at  the classic book  Mathematical methods of statistics
by Harald Cramér. He explains that  rigorously.

Comment: Most mathematical statistics texts mention somewhere that certain 'regularity conditions" are necessary to change the order of differentiation and integration in this computation. Among distributions widely used in practice, these regularity conditions are often met.

Comment: @theoGR: If I understood the proof in that book correctly, it seems like Cramér makes some regularity assumptions on the estimator. I guess my question should then be whether or not "irregular" unbiased estimators exist that violate the Cramér-Rao bound.

Edit: To clarify what I mean: I don't mind regularity conditions on the distributions, so far I haven't been able to find any proofs that don't also impose certain regularity conditions on the estimator.